# $.ajax to call php function not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Sorry to ask this question guys, but I have tried everything and moreover every scenario on this site but cannot get this to work.  I have added alerts and echo's etc... but it just does not seem to be calling the function.  Can anyone help? I got this code from another post here and it was marked as correct answer but does not work for me.

```
<?php
$directory  = "docs/hr/General Information"; 
$images = scandir($directory);
$ignore = Array(".", "..");
$count=1;
echo '<table border=1>';
foreach($images as $dispimage){
    if(!in_array($dispimage, $ignore)){
    echo "<tr id='del$count'><td>$count</td><td>$dispimage</td><td><input type='button' id='delete$count' value='Delete' onclick='deleteFile(\"$dispimage\",$count,\"$directory\");'></td></tr>";
    $count++;
    }
}
echo '</table>';
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteFile(fname,rowid,directory)
{
    $.ajax({ url: "deletefile.php",
        data: {"filename":fname,"directory":directory},
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {
          alert(output);
          $("#del"+rowid).remove();
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

deletefile.php code

```
<?php
$filename = $_POST['filename'];
$path = $_POST['directory'];
if(file_exists($path."/".$filename)) { 
 unlink($path."/".$filename); //delete file
 echo('made it');
}
?>
```

In Console I am getting: uncaught referenceError: deletefile is not defined and it highlights this code `**;'></td></tr><tr id='del2'><td>2</td><td>Final Conference Room Map.pdf</td><td><input type='button' id='delete2' value='Delete' onclick='deletefile("Final Conference Room Map.pdf",2,"docs/hr/General Information");'></td></tr></table><script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>**`

Comment: Did you add an error hander and see what the error is? Did you look at the error console and see if there are any errors?

Comment: How about you check network and console in dev tools? I sure you would find some clue, post it if you find any. And check your PHP error log.

Comment: Inside your onclick, you have a semi-colon at the end of your function call... have you tried removing that?

Comment: Also, in your php, you might want to add an "else" that returns something that the jquery can alert.  This way, if the file is not found, it will still work.  Then you'll at least know if you are getting that far or not.  Another trick I use is to insert "die('here');" at the very top of a php file and see if that works, and keep moving it successively downward in the php file until I find the line causing the issues.... just a way to step through it if you cannot seem to get any errors to throw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your input, they were all good ideas, but in the end, the issue ended up being an IDE issue with codeLobster.  I removed the src="" line from `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>` and let the intellisense fill in the src="js/jquery.js" I finally got it to see the script but I was still getting the deletefile was undefined, well I guess that is case sensitive as my function was deleteFile and my onclick was deletefile,  I sear I had changed that but..., once I changed them to be the same case my delete worked.

Answer (score 0):

My gut tells me that the PHP function "file_exists" is returning FALSE, and since you're only echo'ing if file_exists == true, the post never responds back.

Another thing you'll probably have to check is that the directory and file you're sending are URI encoded. So if there are any non-alpha-numeric characters in there (e.g. spaces), then the javascript POST'ing action will more-than-likely encodeURI before sending, so the dirs and files you gathered earlier will not be identical to those that you send back. So you'll have to de-encode the strings.

I might set up your PHP delete function as:

```
$cleanPath = rawurldecode($path)."/".rawurldecode($filename);
if(file_exists($cleanPath)) { 
    unlink($cleanPath); //delete file
    echo('made it');
} else {
    echo("ERROR: file doesn't exist: " .  $cleanPath);
}
```

This might point you in a direction.

Answer (score 0):

`$dispimage` and `$directory` are strings and I think the quotations are redundant. Could be your problem.

```
onclick='deleteFile(\"$dispimage\",$count,\"$directory\")'
```

Try:

```
onclick='deleteFile($dispimage,$count,$directory)'
```

Comment: No, the quotes are needed even though they're strings.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code and it seems to be working fine. If it doesn't work for you here is something you can try.

- Try upgrading jquery to the latest version.
- Make sure deletefile.php file really exists. Add an error handler function to the ajax call. Simply add this to the ajax function argument:

  error : function(res){
      console.log(res);
      alert(res.statusText);
   }
- Check if the delete function is called or not. Add a simple

> console.log('any text')

inside the function body to check if the function is called or not.

If it still does not work for you, you can modify your code to look something like below and try adding a click event listener using jquery to the buttons.

```
<?php
  //just modify the echo part of your php code to look like this.
  echo "<tr id='del$count'><td>$count</td><td>$dispimage</td><td><input type='button' id='delete$count' value='Delete' data-image='{$dispimage}' data-id='{$count}' data-directory='{$directory}'/></td></tr>";
 //Note:- you can optimize you php script using preg_grep() to scan the directory.
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('input[type=button]').click(function(){
       //call the delete function here.
       deleteFile($(this).attr('data-image'),$(this).attr('data-id'),$(this).attr('data-directory'));
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Sandeep,  i was getting a 404 on the jquery not sure why it could not find it.  so I changed to the code above and I get this error Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined and nothing happens.

Comment: Ok I got it to see the jquery but now I get this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
hrgeneraladmin.php:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteFile is not definedonclick @ hrgeneraladmin.php:1

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteFile is not defined means that function is not defined. you must define the function in your code before you call it.

Answer (score -3):

Try this :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    function deleteFile(fname,rowid,directory)
        {
            $.ajax({ url: "deletefile.php",
                data: {"filename":fname,"directory":directory},
                type: 'post',
                success: function(output) {
                  alert(output);
                  $("#del"+rowid).remove();
                }
            });
        }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't help, `onclick` is clicked when the *DOM is fully loaded with all JavaScript functions*; thus, I don't suspect this being the cause.

Comment: Now the function will be undefined since it is no longer in global scope.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response thepiyush13, i was hopeful but no luck.  when I click the delete button nothing happens.  I am using WAMP but I uploaded the update file to my ubuntu server running Apache and still nothing.  it's like it isn't calling the deletefile function.